# Configure AWS SQS to take runtime exceptions into Dead Letter Queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I am trying to integrate an Async Design with API Gateway -> SQS -> Lambda.

The gateway receives a request and via the SQS integration at gateway we are passing the messages to SQS. The SQS then passes the messages to Lambda and eventually Lambda does the exectution.

I want to handle runtime errors(validation errors, business errors or runtime exceptions).

Please suggest a method to handle such exception with a dead letter queue.

How can I use SQS as a DLQ to receive messages from Lambda based on HTTP status codes from service (in case of runtime failures)?

I tried configuring a SQS as a DLQ Inside Lambda Async Invocation Configuration but even after getting runtime exception the messages are not going to the SQS-DLQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moment the incoming message lands in SQS, the API gateway should send back the success response (HTTP 202) back to the requester. The lambda function will pick the message from the queue and start processing. This will be a synchronous invocation. You need to attach a DLQ to the SQS and configure the `maxReceiveCount` as per your requirement. The standard practice is to set the `maxReceiveCount` to 5. That means in case of failure or exception, the lambda function will re-try 5 times before moving the message in DLQ. However in the handler method of lambda code, the exception need to be thrown back to the caller, otherwise the message will be considered as delivered and will be deleted from SQS. The message will be moved to DLQ automatically after 5th retry without any coding in Lambda.

You may refer to the links below to understand how to configure DLQ.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SetQueueAttributes.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html

This is the visual representation of the solution.

[image]

Comment: I have that exact same architecture but I'm experiencing a weird bug, some events being sent from SQS to DLQ without calling the Lambda. I already checked my SQS, DLQ and Lambda configurations and everything looks good following the docs. Did you have experienced something similar?

Comment: @DavidRearte Can you please check what is the Receive Count of those messages which are going to DLQ ? Does it exceed the maxReceiveCount set for the SetQueueAttributes for the SQS ?

Comment: @manish I have a similar requirement but I want to set up some metadata in the messages going to DLQ based on the exception or issue faced in processing them. That way I can find out which message in the DLQ is there for which reason. Is there any workaround for such a requirement?

Comment: The issue was the concurrency limit of my aws account, the sqs was triggering too many lambdas so the fix was setting the max concurrency limit. This config is directly related with batch size config so you can tweak your flow based on those configs